# Is there a concept of layers in Android ImageView?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am implementing an ImageView which has the following effect: The background is an image to be loaded from an url and there is text on the image. Also there is a shadow behind the text. That is to say, there are three layers on the ImageView. Is there a concept of layer in ImageView which could make the rendering easier?

Comment: Not in ImageView itself. You could of course subclass ImageView and override the onDraw() method to draw something else in the canvas on top of the bitmap. But you better go with normal layouts as FrameLayout or RelativeLayout as @Nun'eChai suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes just map different layers into different Layout containers?

Its simple:

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <--Layer one-->
          <RelativeLayout>
               <--Layer two>

                        <RelativeLayout>
                             <--Layer three-->
                        </RelativeLayout/>


          <RelativeLayout/>


    <RelativeLayout/>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your answer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <!--  FOR SHADOW EFFECT -->
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
    <!--  FOR IMAGE FROM URL -->
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
    <!--  FOR TEXT OVER IMAGE  -->
     <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```